# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, django

is giving this error, but before it was not, I do not know what happened

Model.py

```
class MovRotativo(models.Model):
    checkin = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=False, blank=False)
    checkout = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    valor_hora = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey(Veiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pago = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def horas_total(self):
        return math.ceil((self.checkout - self.checkin).total_seconds() / 3600)

    def total(self):
        return self.valor_hora * self.horas_total()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.veiculo.placa
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def movrotativos_novo(request):
    form = MovRotativoForm(request.POST or  None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return redirect('core_lista_movrotativos')
```

Comment: Post the full Traceback error so the specific line can be isolated.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `checkout` field allows `null` values. I'm guessing the error is raised on the `horas_total` method for records with `null` in the `checkout` field.
The reason this error wasn't raised previously is probably that there weren't any records missing the `checkout` field.

Edit: As for a solution, you can enforce the `checkout` field to have a value. Alternatively you can check for `None`:

```
def horas_total(self):
    if self.checkout is None:
        # handle case where there's no value for checkout 
    return math.ceil((self.checkout - self.checkin).total_seconds() / 3600)
```

Comment: You could add the specific code to illustrate where to check for None.

Comment: def horas_total(self):
        if self.checkout is None:
            pass
        else:
            return math.ceil((self.checkout - self.checkin).total_seconds() / 3600).

Answer (score 0):

Adersource answer should work, but u can try something like this ( you are getting this error because user has not checkout and therefore checkout value is null)-

```
`def horas_total(self):
     if self.checkout is None:
        # handle case where there's no value for checkout 
        self.checkout = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
     return math.ceil((self.checkout - self.checkin).total_seconds() / 3600)`
```

you may have to tweak it a little bit based on your code